# How to set an ol.style.text using a source in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var cbcWFS = new ol.source.GeoJSON({
    projection: 'EPSG:3857',
    url: 'http://localhost:7070/geoserver/CuerpoBomberosCurico/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=CuerpoBomberosCurico:CuerpoBomberosCurico&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application/json'
  });

var cuerpoBomberosVector = new ol.layer.Vector({
      title: 'Cuerpo Bomberos',
      source: cbcWFS,
      style: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
          scale: 0.04,
          src: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27798645/fireman/truck65.svg'
        }),
        text: new ol.style.Text({
          text: 'Hello',
          scale: 1.3,
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#000000'
          }),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#FFFF99',
            width: 3.5
          })
        })
      })
  });
```

But now, in the part of "Text", I'd like to use the value that it comes from the source.

Any idea how to develop it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve this using a style function on your vector layer. This is a function that is called whenever a feature is rendered, with the feature and the view resolution as arguments. The function is supposed to return an array of styles. The official vector-layer example shows how to do this. To see the example live, go to http://openlayers.org/en/v3.3.0/examples/vector-layer.html and zoom in a few times.

In your specific case, you would have to change your code to something like this:

```
var cuerpoBomberosVector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  title: 'Cuerpo Bomberos',
  source: cbcWFS,
  style: (function() {
    var style = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Icon({
        scale: 0.04,
        src: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27798645/fireman/truck65.svg'
      }),
      text: new ol.style.Text({
        text: 'Hello',
        scale: 1.3,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: '#000000'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: '#FFFF99',
          width: 3.5
        })
      })
    });
    var styles = [style];
    return function(feature, resolution) {
      style.getText().setText(feature.get("text"));
      return styles;
    };
  })()
});
```

The above snippet assumes that your features have an attribute 'text' that holds the text you want to have as label.

Comment: Won't this change the text for every feature on this layer?

Comment: Not if you make this change on the text style that you return from the styleFunction.